# Good books on geometric recursion

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation, recursion, tessellations

I was looking at my bathroom tiles, which were an interesting sort of repeating pattern of different squares and rectangles, and wondering how to model them as a recursion formula. Does anyone know any good or interesting books on recursion? Advanced level is fine with me.

For my level of background, I just wrapped up Calculus II and am taking up to Calculus IV and Linear Algebra later this year. Also, I come from a software engineering background so I'm familiar with writing recursive graphics, but I feel like the way I write it is not that elegant and sophisticated.

Thank you!

Comment: For bathroom tiles it might be more interesting to read about [wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group).

Comment: About wallpaper groups see as well [this reference](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/Gallery/Symmetry/Tilings/Sanderson/index.html).